# How to use a trigger in PostgreSQL to create a new schema when a new row is inserted in a table?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table that holds clients, I have just one client per country, and for each row in this table I must create a new schema and replicate some tables. Like this:

```
Clients table's columns: 

client      country
----------  -----------
john doe    US
jane doe    UK
```

Schemas:

```
clients_US
clients_UK
```

I need to create a trigger to create those schemas automatically everytime a new client is added to the clients table, using the country column data as part of the schema's name.

In a perfect world this would work, but it clearly doesn't:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gcpmanager.create_sle_schema() 
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
    'begin 
    CREATE SCHEMA "clients_" + new.country
    AUTHORIZATION postgres;
        return new;
    end;';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gcpmanager.create_sle_schema() 
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
begin 
  execute 'CREATE SCHEMA clients_'||new.country||' AUTHORIZATION postgres';
  return new;
end;
$$
```

Btw: the string concatenation operator in PostgreSQL is `||` not `+` (that is for numbers)

Comment: Probably needs a quite_ident() call and a security definer. :-)

Comment: I've used quote_ident since I want the capital letters, thanks. About that security definer, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic SQL for this:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN